# AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask seems to load m3u8 file twice

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avurlasset

I am using `AssetPersistenceManager` from this Apple Sample : [Using AVFoundation to play and persist http live streams](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams)
I create an `AVURLAsset` with a playlist master url, then call `downloadStream(for:)` with this asset, and the `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` complete download successfully !

It saves a folder named `286943_chapter_01_C955A55455AC0C4E.movpkg` which contains the downloaded segments, my `.m3u8` file and a `StreamInfoBoot.xml` file. 
The `StreamInfoBook.xml` file contains references between local segment (or `.frag`) file and `m3u8` segment URL.

However, those urls are signed and generated by Cloudfront. And some times, some URLs inside the `.m3u8` file doesn't match URLs in `StreamInfoBook.xml` because of `Expires` parameter of cloudfrount.

So I think maybe `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` is calling the `.m3u8` file **twice** : Once to save the `.m3u8` and once to download segments and write `StreamInfoBook.xml`.

Does anyone already faced this issue ? What could I do to check if my Asset is playable offline or not ?
Do you have any suggestion ?

Here is an exemple of not matching segment URLs

**In .m3u8 downloaded file :**

https: //ezvoiznbov32f.cloudfront.net/file/265579/audio/chapter_08_10.mp3?Expires=**1576159816**&Signature=vfAYZ8ivP7yKeiranpba3R24gTSxexX4Nb1VjbDrR917pyFQqi2DMMMf8gi3LcueKXxv0FITprXzLXV62Py0Ph4nMxp8ixf5qG5sYnW1JcO74BxNfJE~DEurN~yQgczNBOK4b~bEXrDDZId1AweYJrgjZtjSoyUwAGXf~LA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAAFEFNOSQQ34Q

**In `StreamInfoBook.xml` file :**

https: //ezvoiznbov32f.cloudfront.net/file/265579/audio/chapter_08_10.mp3?Expires=**1576159817**&Signature=PZ~tqOeIa3Vm26qKTFYU1LCGfvsWNpkUDMi3eFr~EhyRTLj66CDInSwfpoorYjl4Kl4B9eQ1W8ZzTlIMDGvs36wJ235JOszeov23IuIOzAJTlNw7zQYEd4Y1tq~nyZinpFoyDRGk0CelKOhH91Itb3rpQUeMN6lDhO-cq1X1OM_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAAFEFNOSQQ34Q

I'm testing with iOS 13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, answering myself :

After a very long time trying to make `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` works in background while the application is killed by the system, I finally switched to `AVAssetDownloadTask`.

Now everything is working perfectly ! It's like magic !

The difference between aggregate and normal tasks is in media selections. But I don't need it for now....